# Tensorflow model converter - converted model does not work in browser/Javascript

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, model

I am converting a object detection model , tried with must custom generated model & also using ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17 model frozen_inference_graph.pb
using the following syntax for tfjs-converter
latest version of tensorflowjs 0.15
latest version of tfjs_converter
Chrome browser Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)
OS Ubuntu-16.04
Same error is on Windows 10 - Chrome

`tensorflowjs_converter  --input_format=tf_frozen_model --output_format=tensorflowjs --output_node_names='detection_boxes,detection_classes,detection_scores,num_detections'  --saved_model_tags=serve ./frozen_inference_graph_ssd.pb ./web_model_ssd`

When I load the model using javascript

````
const WEIGHTS_URL ='http://localhost:1234/web/web_model_ssd/weights_manifest.json';
console.log('starting ........');
window.onload = () => modelPromise = tf.loadFrozenModel(MODEL_URL, WEIGHTS_URL);```

I get this error in console
io_utils.ts:116 Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: byte length of Float32Array should be a multiple of 4
    at new Float32Array (<anonymous>)
    at a (io_utils.ts:116)
    at Object.decodeWeights (io_utils.ts:79)
    at e.<anonymous> (frozen_model.ts:113)
    at callbacks.ts:17
    at Object.next (callbacks.ts:17)
    at i (callbacks.ts:17)
````